# Why Do Some Components Not Respect DPI Scaling on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts, dpi, scaling

This has been a problem for me for too long, and I have no idea how to resolve. I use a Dell Laptop with a docking station, the 14" Touch Screen has a greater than HD resolution.

This means that when using the laptop screen, I have the displayed scaled to 125%. Generally this works well, and when my laptop is docked and connected to my two desk screens (1920x1080) I have the display scaled at 100%.

The problem is that randomly some desktop components do not respect the DPI scaling settings. e.g. PowerBI (a Microsoft application!) was working fine for me yesterday while docked. Now today some of the text is wrong, see screenshot.

Notice how the popup autocomplete window text is too big, and therefore cutoff. What confuse me is that this was fine yesterday. This issue seems to happen in Visual Studio and other Microsoft products more often than other applications, which is extra frustrating because I'm running their OS (W10 v1511) and their software and it doesnt work!!

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Restarting pc between using it with different monitor settings might help. I know this isn't an ideal solution, but I don't know better.

Comment: My laptop was off when I docked it this morning then switched on while docked. So i havn't changed the monitor config since boot.